# Sort character array using java comparator

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

Sort a character array lexicographically with an additional condition that all c's comes before all b's. This could be done manually but I want to code it via inbuilt sorting using comparators. The code I wrote -

```
static class Sort implements Comparator<Character> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Character x, Character y) {
        if(x == 'c' && y == 'b') {
            return y - x;
        }
        return x - y;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abracadabra";
    int n = s.length();
    Character[] res = new Character[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        res[i] = s.charAt(i);
    }
    Arrays.sort(res, new Sort());
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
}
```

Gives output: [a, a, a, a, a, b, c, b, d, r, r]. The c only comes before one of the b's. If I change the comparator to the following then it gives the correct output.

```
public int compare(Character x, Character y) {
        if(x == 'c' && y == 'b' || x == 'b' && y == 'c') {
            return y - x;
        }
        return x - y;
    }
```

My question is why in both cases returning "y-x" gives the correct answer? If in one case returning "y-x" was correct then in the other case shouldn't returning "x-y" would have been correct? Instead of "y-x", returning a -1 or +1 doesn't work either. Pl. explain what is happening internally. Thanks!

Comment: If you invert the arguments, you have to negate the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that if passing `'c'` and `'b'` makes the comparison return a negative value, then passing `'b'` and `'c'` should return a positive one (And your first version returns a negative number in that case instead). If the function doesn't return consistent results no matter the order of arguments, the sort algorithm is going to produce a garbage order.

Consider this version:

```java
    public int compare(Character x, Character y) {
        if (x == 'c' && y == 'b') {
            return -1;
        } else if (x == 'b' && y == 'c') {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return x.compareTo(y);
        }
    }
```

Comment: (I'm not a big fan of using subtraction to compare two values; been bitten by overflow issues a few times in C programs that did that)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `System.out.println()` to understand how it work:

#### Code

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "abracadabra";
        int n = s.length();
        
        System.out.println("X Y\tX Y\t[if] VALUE");
        System.out.println();
        
        Character[] res = new Character[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            res[i] = s.charAt(i);
        }
        
        int min = 'a';
        
        Arrays.sort(res, new Comparator<Character>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Character x, Character y) {
                System.out.print(y + " " + x + "\t" + (x-min) + " " + (y-min) + "\t");
                if(x == 'c' && y == 'b') {
                    System.out.println("true " + (y - x));
                    return y - x;
                }
                System.out.println("     " + (x - y));
                return x - y;
            }
        });
        System.out.println("#################################\nResult:\n" + Arrays.toString(res));
    }
}
```

#### Console:

```
X Y X Y   [if] VALUE

a b 1 0        1
b r 17 1       16
r a 0 17       -17
b a 0 1        -1
a a 0 0        0
b c 2 1   true -1
a c 2 0        2
c a 0 2        -2
a a 0 0        0
c d 3 2        1
r d 3 17       -14
b d 3 1        2
c a 0 2        -2
a a 0 0        0
a a 0 0        0
c b 1 2        -1
a b 1 0        1
a b 1 0        1
b r 17 1       16
d r 17 3       14
r r 17 17      0
c a 0 2        -2
a a 0 0        0
b a 0 1        -1
a a 0 0        0
#################################
Result:
[a, a, a, a, a, b, c, b, d, r, r]
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [Javadoc for `java.util.Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html). It says for the method `compare()`:

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

For your case, it means that `compare( 'b', 'c' )` should return something greater than zero, and for `compare( 'c', 'b' )` something less than zero, while the natural order would be the opposite.

But your first implementation (that wrong one) covered only the case `compare( 'c', 'b' )`, but not `compare( 'b', 'c' )`, so that the method would return the default value then.

Your second and correctly working implementation fixed that.